# Ember-index is not producing index.jsp

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use ember-index add on to generate index.jsp file instead of index.html. I have installed the `ember-index` addon and did the required changes as well.

My `config/environment.js` file looks like below

```
/* eslint-env node */

'use strict';

module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'user-profile',
    output: 'index.jsp',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'hash',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },
    'ember-index': {
        output: 'index.jsp',
        content: {
            file: 'example.txt',
            includeInOutput: true,
            includeInIndexHtml: false
        }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };
return ENV;
};
```

Also my `example.txt` file looks like

```
<meta content="Example">
<h2>html to jsp</h2>
```

and finally in my `index.html` I  have added below snippet

```
{{content-for 'ember-index'}}
```

But now when i am trying to build the ember project with ember build I am not able to see `index.jsp` file in my dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

With a fresh app, this addon works as expected. Walk through the steps for the minimal example using a new Ember app, and you'll find what you missed.

Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the index.jsp? It is at dist/export/index.jsp after running `ember build`.

Did you forget to add the tag in your index.html? The readme specifies that for your files to be used, they must be specified like this:

```
<!-- app/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     ...
     {{content-for 'ember-index-1'}}
     {{content-for 'ember-index-2'}}
  </head>
  <body>
      ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as i know the export folder will be created when we provide output folder as export but i haven't specify anything like that and yes i have provided the content-for tag at the right place still not able to get the index.jsp file.

Comment: My advice to you is to create a fresh app and compare configurations. If you're still having problems, possibly open an issue for the addon. I've not used this one myself. Good luck!